# Make certain keywords in Laravel search go directly to certain pages

Tags: php, laravel, search, design-patterns, database-design

I've implemented a basic search on my Laravel site that searches a table of manufacturers in the database, and I'm now wanting to improve it (I could be wrong, but Scout seems like too much overkill right now to go through the headache of implementing).

I've come across sites that allow you to search by both manufacturer ("OnePlus") or manufacturer and model ("OnePlus 9T"), whereupon searching for any of those terms will take you directly to the OnePlus manufacturer page.

How should I approach implementing something like this with my own manufacturers table, and implementing something like this for manufacturer models (in the product sense, not MVC sense) when I don't have tables in the database to represent them? In the latter case, is creating a table of models for every manufacturer the only way to do this?

Comment: Separate table of search terms, each linked through a relationship to a specific manufacturer in the manufacturer's table. When user inputs search term, look through search terms table first, if finds match (that allows you to match both "one plus" and "oneplus" and other variations to the same manufacturer) then return corresponding manufacturer's page. If not proceed to search through manufacturer's table as planned.

Or don't implement search terms as a separate table, but as a separate column on the manufacturer's table.

Comment: @GilesBennett So you're saying instead of separate tables of models/search terms for each manufacturer, one single search terms table with a column for/relationship to a manufacturer? I have to admit that didn't even occur to me.

Comment: @GilesBennett For the relationship between the search term table and manufacturer, would a one-to-one relationship be best?

Comment: Each search term table entry would link to one specific manufacturer. Each manufacturer would link to (potentially) many different search terms.

Comment: @GilesBennett So a table for OnePlus, for example, and then another one containing all Search Terms including OnePlus, Apple, Samsung, etc? What Laravel relationship would be best to describe the relationship between those tables them? For that matter, would I need to set up Search (terms) as a model just to set a relationship on it?

Comment: @GilesBennett I see now that you're saying no individual manufacturer tables at all - just a Manufacturers table to contain all manufacturers, and a Search Terms table to contain all search terms, and then a relationship between those two tables. I think that makes sense.